# How to load GeoJson file with sencha touch

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, jsonp, geojson

I work for a project of mobile application with sencha touch, and I have a problem with my models to retreive informations.
i will show you my model and my json file content

**json file :** ( i make it very simple just to test, i deleted the geometry line)

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
            "properties": {"graphic": "img/restaurant.png","Name": "Igor Tihonov", "Country":"Sweden", "City":"Gothenburg"}
            }

        ]
}
```

My model :

```
 Ext.regModel('Features', {
        hasMany: {model: 'Properties', name: 'properties'}

    });


    Ext.regModel('Properties', {
        fields: ['graphic', 'Name', 'Country', 'City'],
        associations: [
            {type: 'belongsTo', model: 'Features'}
        ]
    });
```

Store :

```
 Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'Features',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'poi2.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'features'
            }
        },
        autoLoad:true
    });
```

i have more than a week since i'm blocked, i wish that you could help me !
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the 'type' property, I would recommend:

- lose the first model and all associations
- set the model on your store to 'Properties' (this works, because your rootProperty is set to 'features)
- change your JSON so the properties are not another level deeper down your JSON:

  ```
  {  
      "type": "FeatureCollection",  
      "features": [  
          {  
              "graphic": "img/restaurant.png",  
                  "Name": "Igor Tihonov",   
              "Country":"Sweden",  
              "City":"Gothenburg"}  
          },  
          {  
              "graphic": "img/restaurant2.png",  
              "Name": "Igor Tihonov2",   
              "Country":"Sweden",  
              "City":"Gothenburg"}    
          }  
      ]  
  }
  ```

[edit]
To maintain the json format, use the following approach:

- set the rootproperty to 'features'
- add a 'feature' model containing only a 'hasMany' association to your property model (which contains the actual fields)
- set the model of your store to your feature model

[/edit]

Comment: I deleted the "Features" model and its associations, and i changed the model to "Properties" in my store...  But it still dont work ! :(

Comment: I have to keep this format because its the Geojson format for openlayers !

Comment: Then you need to add another model to represent the extra layer, I'll edit my answer

Comment: this how i getting attributes is that wrong ??  this.itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            
   '{Name}' 
   
        );

Comment: If your templates won't get to complex, you could also just use Ext.Template:  
this.itemTpl = ['{name}'];

Comment: @getting back to originally posted code; it's almost the same, but I would suggest losing the 'belongsTo' association you had; you don't need it.